ADB suddenly not finding device
Have been connecting to my device with ADB for days without issue, but suddenly it's not in the list (adb.exe devices returns an empty list).
The device shows up in device manager (Android composite ADB Interface).
I have so far:

ran adb.exe kill-server
restarted the device
replaced the device with another identical device
replaced the usb-cable
reinstalled the drivers
restarted the computer
checked so that I have the latest version of ADB
had a gander in the system event viewer... (can't see anything interesting)

I'm kinda running out of ideas here.
USB debugging isn't the issue. Windows 11, running adb on cmd mostly.

Hardly a programming question.

@ArkadiuszDrabczyk Well, I'm using a C# winforms program to access the device using adb, so kinda, but if there is another forum where the question will fit better I'm happy for the suggestion
